# Set attribute to css file

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

I have a CSS file with the name box.cs that contains the following code;

```
#box_overlay 
{
  z-index: 10000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

#box_icon 
{
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

I want to call this css file from a script; 
     `iframe.setAttribute("style", "/styles/box.cs");` but it's not letting me. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are calling /styles/box.cs is this typo mistake ? your file name box.css

Comment: change a file extension from .cs to .css, use a relative path (add a dot ./styles/box.css)

Comment: You cant add a file to an inline style attribute